# Meaning of &st[3]-st in printf("%ld", &st[3]-st)

Tags: c

I'm new to C and in an exercise, I have to write the output of the following portion of code, which is `3`. But I couldn't understand why it is that.

```
int main() {
    char st[100]="efgh"; 
    printf ("\n%ld\n",&st[3]-st); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: To add to the answers that have already been given, arrays are consecutive in memory, and sizeof(char) is 1. That means if the first letter of the string 'e' is at the address 10, f is at 11 g is at 12 and h is at 13. 13-10 == 3.

Comment: The code has 2 instances of undefined behavior: `%ld` instead of `%td` and missing `#include <stdio.h>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use an array in an expression, unless it is the argument of `&` or `sizeof`, it evaluates to the address of its first element.

Thus `&st[3] - st` evaluates as `&st[3] - &st[0]`, which is just pointer arithmetic: The difference between the addresses of two array elements is just the difference between their indices, i.e. `3 - 0`, which gives `3`.

The only problem is that the result is of type `ptrdiff_t`, but `printf` `%ld` expects a `long int`. If those types are different on your machine, it won't work. In a [`printf()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6) format string, the correct length modifier for `ptrdiff_t` is `t` — use `"\n%td\n"`.

Answer (score 3):

By definition, `&st[3]` is the same as `st+3`. `st+3-st` is `3`. (`st` in that expression decays from array to a pointer. For portability, the printf format string should technically have `%td` instead of `%ld`.)

Comment: I think your answer is not good for a beginner. You use terms like `decays` which OP most likely wont understand. Also your missing some basic explanation imho.